# Howto export from EXCHANGE - mail Contacts, "Global Adress List"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I have an Exchange server account configured in Outlook.

How can I export all my mail and contacts including "Global Address List"?.

Or at least be sure everything is safely stored in  local Outlook?

Added:
Q1: Can I do this with archive (Will the archive me local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **free** [Export Messages to MSG Format](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesExportMSG/) and [Export Contacts to MSG Format](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookContactsExportMSG/) tools. Both tools respect your folder structure and you can get your items back anytime using free importers for [messages](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportMSG/) and [contacts](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookContactsImportMSG/). I'm one of the developers of all these tools.

GAL export is not supported at the time however.